Implementing Localization in Django REST Framework
In an ongoing development project of DRF, I have to support the translation for multiple languages.
My question is how should I do it.

Like upgrading existing APIs with the translated response (need to alter the viwesets and serializers).
Having a separate translation APIs.
The data which is added from the CMS is how it's translation to be done, cause from the CMS the translation can be updated as well and storing so much of the data for each language in the DB doesn't sound good to me.

Additionally there are many table's who's data is stored in DB added by any admin and can be updated, added new as well how those translation needs to be taken care of.

I know how the translation works with django and the Rosetta as well for the updatable interface.
My question is how should I approach it for the entire project.
Please guide me, if you can it would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Please clarify what exactly you'll be translating. Usually translation concerns the UI, which in the case of DRF doesn't exist. DRF provides an API for data, the UI for it is elsewhere.

@deceze The data that has been added from the CMS has to be translated into the respective language.
So specifically both the labels and all (static data) that are present at the side of the application the data that has been added from the CMS by an Admin, and there the data entered by the user will definitely stored in the user's respective language as what they have entered into our system.

So the translations are just data? Then tell us a bit more about how you want that to be structured or how it should behave.

@deceze, So there are the API's that I've built using the DRF.
As of now, it's returning the JSON response, At the client side the translated data has to be presented based on the user's language.

In the same strucure the translated data has to be sent to the user.

Now what would be the best approach for me to work with all this scenario's.
